# UpdatePanel não atualiza

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net

Tenho o seguinte updatePanel:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" >
        <Scripts>

        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panelTreeView" runat="server"   UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
          <ContentTemplate>
<div class="easy-tree">

     <asp:TreeView  ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ImageSet="Arrows" ForeColor="Black"     OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged" >
         <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" />
         <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="Black"     HorizontalPadding="5px" NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
         <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
     <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" BackColor="#E2D2D2"                         HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />

</asp:TreeView>

    </div>
              </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Quero atualizar o treeview, em uma determinado momento.

Método codebhind:

```
public metodoQualquer(){
this.panelTreeView.Update();
}
```

Mas nada ocorre.

Comment: O seu código não demonstra quem é o trigger do update, você colocou UpdateMode="Conditional", logo algo precisa disparar o update. Você não avisou que os filhos são triggers, não definiu um trigger e o updatePanel não tem um pai updatePanel que faça atualização, logo não tem disparo definido para esse updatePanel.

Comment: E como fica? coloquei ChildrenAsTriggers="true" mas nada ainda.

Comment: Então primeiro atualiza o código da pergunta, depois aproveita e coloca o código do OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged". Não adianta chamar update se o componente não tem informações novas para mostrar.

Comment: atualizei, mas meu metodo faz sim alguma coisa. cria um node novo, toda vez tenho que pressionar f5, ou da um redirect.

Comment: Você colocou no elemento errado man, é no updatepanel e não no scriptmanager. Posta o código do evento de postback também.

Comment: Eu nunca vi colocar ChildrenAsTriggers="true" dentro do ScriptManager, porque não retira ele e tenta.

Comment: @Marconi Fui eu que expliquei pra ele que não tinha trigger no updatepanel, ele escolheu esse trigger, mas colocou no lugar errado.

Comment: @Malkaviano Sinta-se a vontade pra postar a resposta!
Você deve coloca-la na resposta não no comentario.